# I need to add to tables to database using InstallSchema.php How can i do that?

Tags: magento-2.1, install-script

Below class is my InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Test2\Helloworld\Setup;

use \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $tableName = $setup->getTable('base_price');

        if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            $table = $setup->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'width',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Width'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'height',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Height'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'price_component',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Price Component'
                )
                ->setComment('Test2_Helloworld - price');
            $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I need to add another table for color price with 3 columns id, color and price_component

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add as many table as you want in your installSchema file. Refer below code

```
<?php

namespace Test2\Helloworld\Setup;

use \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $tableName = $setup->getTable('base_price');
        $colorTableName = $setup->getTable('color_price');

        if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            $table = $setup->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'width',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Width'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'height',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Height'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'price_component',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Price Component'
                )
                ->setComment('Test2_Helloworld - price');
            $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

    if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($colorTableName) != true) {
            $table = $setup->getConnection()
                ->newTable($colorTableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'color',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'color'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'price_component',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'price_component '
                )
                ->setComment('Color Price');
            $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }        

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

In case if you have have already installed your module you can follow below two **methods**

**Method 1**

Go to your database and find table `setup_modules` find your modulename and remove your entry. This will initiate your setup script and you will able to see your new tables.

**Method 2**

Create updagradeSchema

Create a new file UpgradeSchema.php in Setup Folder and place this code

```
namespace Test2\Helloworld\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $this->addColorTabe($setup);
        }
    }

    /**
     * add Color Table
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function addColorTabe(SchemaSetupInterface $setup)
    {

    $colorTableName = $setup->getTable('color_price');

    if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($colorTableName) != true) {
            $table = $setup->getConnection()
                ->newTable($colorTableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'color',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'color'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'price_component',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'price_component '
                )
                ->setComment('Color Price');
            $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and change the `setup_version` to `1.0.1` in `<moduledir>/etc/module.xml`. This will update your module schema.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, i think you just need to copy the block :

```
$tableName = $setup->getTable('base_price');

    if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
        $table = $setup->getConnection()
            ->newTable($tableName)
            ->addColumn(
                'id',
                Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary' => true
                ],
                'ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'width',
                Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false],
                'Width'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'height',
                Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false],
                'Height'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'price_component',
                Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false],
                'Price Component'
            )
            ->setComment('Test2_Helloworld - price');
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }
```

And it will create the second table, i'm not 100% sure :)

Comment: I tried that but didnt work @Nundra

Comment: As said by Userpk this should work, i just check and i do it, you are sure to use different name ? Check your variable etc...